# Mining investment

Tags: mining, mining-pools, solo-mining

I was wondering if a mining contract is a worthwhile endeavor. I hesitate to call it an "investment" as the principal, the cost of the contract, is lost at the start.

Anyone have any comments or experiences to share?

Comment: Hi there. Your question is rather open-ended, and any answers would likely be opinionated and subjective. This forum is more geared towards technical queries that have specific, objective answers. You'd probably have more luck on one of the Reddit boards: reddit.com/r/ethereum

Comment: Welcome. I tend to agree with Richard. It's a good question but probably better suited to another board. Possibly here: https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/